# Two-phase lubricating flow or cavitation

Tags: modelica, dymola

How should I handle two-phase lubricating flow in Dymola?

I want to model the possible cavitation or air that is within an IC engine oil pump, but I do not know how I could manage the fluid in that part.

Modeling the oil medium on one side and the cavitation losses on the flow model or trying to model the possible combination of air and oil in the same medium.

Comment: @matth I read you in that post [two-phase-modelica-media-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908292/two-phase-modelica-media-example/34992638?noredirect=1#comment57713374_34992638) 

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: That is a very general question, there are many different models you could use for two-phase flow, for the fluid properties, for the cavitation, for your pump etc. What equations from which publications do you use? Modelica is just a programming language and you can implement more or less any equation in it. What have you done so far and what is the next step (in other words: What exactly are you asking)?

Comment: If your question is only about the fluid properties: You have a problem, because the Media interfaces in the Modelica Standrad Library are made for either multiple phases OR multiple components. A suggestion for a new interface that can handle multi-component mixtures with multiple phases simulataneously is described here: http://dx.doi.org/10.3384/ecp15118653

Comment: Thanks @matth, about your first comment, the issue is that I have hardly found out literature about that topic, so I don't know exactly how to face it. I thought you might know any paper that could lead me at the beginning.
Maybe, what I need is a multiple components media, since the oil-air problem appears when the pump is working and mixes air, that is in repose/residual, and pumped oil.
By the way, thanks for the article, I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, we experimented with modeling cavitation in hydraulic systems by using a parametric model similar to the way [one might model an ideal diode](https://books.google.com/books?id=7vcGCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=ideal+diode+parametric&source=bl&ots=cZYOYefF2i&sig=p5N8wWcQJ_z0WB9sNUBj_AKvdUY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVseLx0sXKAhVsvIMKHbEKCCMQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=ideal%20diode%20parametric&f=false).

Applied to cavitation, what you do is introduce a component that represents cavitation volume.  When pressure is above 0, cavitation volume is zero.  Whenever the pressure would drop below 0, you simply create a larger cavitation volume.  So if you model this parametrically in terms of a parameter `s`, you get:

`P(s) = if s<0 then 0 else s;
V(s) = if s<0 then -s else 0;`

This makes `s` the independent variable to be solved for.  Of course, cavitation has to have some consequence for this to be non-singular.  In our case, we modeled these cavitation volumes in hydraulic actuators so the cavitation allowed (for example) a piston to move without lowering the pressure.  But that was a high-pressure hydraulic actuation system.  I'm not sure what cavitation would do for your system...perhaps limit flow?

This isn't exactly an answer, more of a hint.  I was going to make it a comment, but I couldn't fit everything as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your clue @Michael Tiller.
I need to do a more thorough research to manage the model, though I caught your idea for handling the function.